# catch sign in error when using identity UserManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync()

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, identity

I've got a user linked to Identity. It all works I can login and Register and all data is good.
Now I want to catch the error that is happening when Sign In fails. I get the messages in the console, but I would like to catch them to log them or return them or one of them.
The errors:

```
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager[0]
      Invalid password for user.
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager[2]
      User failed to provide the correct password.
```

If you have any other tips they are of course very welcome.

```
public async Task<UserReplyDTO> LoginAsync(UserLoginDTO userLoginDTO)
        {
            var user = await _userRepo.GetUserByEmail(userLoginDTO.Email);

            var result = await _signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user, userLoginDTO.Password, false);

            //var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(userLoginDTO.Email, userLoginDTO.Password, false, false);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                UserReplyDTO userReplyDTO = new UserReplyDTO() { Email = user.Email, Id = user.Id, UserName = user.UserName, Role = user.Role };

                string token = _tokenService.GetToken(user);
                userReplyDTO.Token = token;

                return userReplyDTO;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new UserLoginException("Bad UserName or Password!");
            }
        }
```

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost("login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(UserLoginDTO userLoginDto)
        {
            try
            {
                var user = await _authService.LoginAsync(userLoginDto);
                return Ok(user);
            }
            catch (UserLoginException ex)
            {
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }
            catch (AggregateException ex)
            {
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```